# Navigation drawer - items overlapping in horizontal orientation

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

In my Nav Drawer, I have a ListView and below that some ImageButtons. To show the Listview on top and rest of the views at the bottom of the screen, I used relative layout as below.

In this scenario, when I rotate my phone to horizontal orientation (e.g. not enough length to show ListView and others), the ImageButtons overlap the ListView (like floating DIVs in HTML).

I tried using LinearLayout with layout_gravity = "bottom" for the container of ImageButtons, but then the buttons were placed adjacent to the Listview, rather than at the bottom of the scren.

Please guide me how to implement this correctly.

```
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/extrabuttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/credit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/information" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_exit" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/extrabuttons"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="@string/ad_tag" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is what it should be looked like & how it is looked like in vertical mode**
[image]

**This is how it is looked like in horizontal mode**
[image]

Comment: show snap what u want ?

Answer (score 0):

Then Try to do this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight="6" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/extrabuttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/credit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/extrabuttons"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="string/ad_tag" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry for delayed reply ... actually this one I tried already ... if you put that line, layout_alignParentBottom doesn't work any more ... means my imagebuttons lay just below the ListView, not at the bottom of the screen

Comment: then use linear layout with weights @AbdullahFahim check new edits to answer

Answer (score 0):

The layout components are overlapped because you have used Relative layout as parent.Try to use Linear layout with vertical  orientation, instead of Relative layout.

Comment: I mentioned in my question, I tried that already ... but with LinearLayout, I am not being able align the Imagebuttons to the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is bit late. I will suggest to make seperate xml layout and add this layout to listview with 'addFooterView' method. It will bound that xml always in last of that list view. I hope it will help you.